# oracle jdk 13 installed but not working

Tags: java, deb, jdk, oracle

I have installed Oracle JDK 13 using the .deb file given on their [official website](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk13-downloads-5672538.html) .

But when I run the `java` command, it is showing:

```
Command 'java' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install default-jre            
sudo apt install openjdk-11-jre-headless
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package `jdk-13.0.2_linux-x64_bin.deb` 
installs to `/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.2/bin/{java, javac, ....}`, I.e. to use the oracle java, you will have to setup an "/etc/alternatives" link to a system PATH :

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.2/bin/java 2000
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/jdk-13.0.2/bin/javac 2000
```

And when that is done you can select the preferred java version (If more than one version is installed) :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac
```

Comment: Running `update-java-alternatives` may be safer.

Comment: What is the 2000 for?

Comment: 2000 is just a random number different from already present numbering.  The "update-alternatives program" will set a new number.